# What is the difference between `asyncio.open_connection` and `socket.socket.accept()`

Tags: python, sockets, wifi, espressif-idf

I'm trying to connect a device ESP32C3 (implementing Espressif's SDK ESP-IDF). This device creates a WiFi hotspot and streams some data.

I use Windows WiFi connection panel to connect the ESP32C3 device by providing the appropriate password. Then, I see it in `ipconfig` output.

We did a quick prototyping using a Python client script, this script is able to open the connection and retrieve streamed data. This script opens the connection using `reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(HOST, PORT)`.

Now we wanted to integrate this in some legacy code we have that used to open a connection using:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST,PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Accepted")
```

But then `s.accept()` hangs forever and connection is not established.

Is there any reason why `asyncio.open_connection(HOST, PORT)` would work while `socket.socket.accept()` fails?

Comment: `open_connection()` is an asynchronous  client-side method. `accept()` is a blocking server-side method. They are not equivalent in any way. Your question is based on a misconception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between `asyncio.open_connection` and `socket.socket.accept()`

These functions have basically nothing in common. They are not used for the same purpose, but for the opposite purpose: `asyncio.open_connection` is called in the client to establish a connection to the server. `socket.accept` is called in the server to accept a connection from a client.

So, `open_connection` is not a replacement for `accept` - this would be `socket.connect` instead. Similar `accept` is not a replacement for `open_connection`, this would be `asyncio.start_server` instead.

Comment: I need to investigate this but this is likely why it does not work how we expect. We definitely need to work as a client, but out legacy code used to work as a server. Your post helped, thank you.

Comment: All right, I confirm this was the actual problem. Misunderstanding client/server code subtility.